# managing a composite object in Ember - ObjectController, ArrayController,?

Tags: ember.js

I am a bit unsure about how to implement this in Ember and preserve things like two way data binding. I'm a bit unsure whether Ember could support the object model we currently have. I have a menu, that is made up of menu_headers and items. It could look like this:

```
menu
  menu_header
    menu_header
      items
      items
      items
  menu_header
    items
    items
```

I have structure so that menu, menu_header, and item are three separate objects (as can be seen here:   [ember and iterating through a json array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832852/ember-and-iterating-through-a-json-array-of-objects) ). I have created a menu route but I'm not sure how to really structure this further. For example, will this synthesize an ObjectController, an ArrayController, multiple ObjectController's? It seems like the examples of ArrayController are a bunch of one items and not a composite like this?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to handle this, based on your previous example, is it safe to assume you aren't using any client side record management (Ember Data/Ember Model)?

Comment: correct, no client site record management.

Comment: @kingpin2k thx, been playing with it but still a bit at a loss esp with how to set up outlets

Comment: So based on my other answer, which may be worthless, but still worth noting, can you explain the need for two way binding etc?